# Outlook automatically changing the font size of certain words only, when sending an e-mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts, size

I answerd and e-mail I got on my Outlook app on my iPhone.

To my horror, when looking at the e-mail after I sent it, Outlook seemed to have changed the font size of certain parts of my e-mail. It looks like it tracks certain words like "as we mentioned before", or "we don't have the capacity to help you do ......".

It was an e-mail sent to tell someone that my team could not help them, but Outlook enlarged certain text in that e-mail, so that it sounded horrible.
And that happend automatically.

The parts that got a larger font size (twice the size of the rest of the text), were:
"...as we mentioned before..."
and
"..nor do we have the capacity to help you....".

So now it sounds like I "shouted out", and on purpuse changed the font-size of those words. Is this a new feature? If so, it is a horrible one.
An e-mail changes the whole context if you emphasise some words on purpose, or add large letters.

How can I turn this off?
I have not found any mention of this when Googleing the error.

When I use the Outlook app on my PC, it sometimes changes font and styling when sending an e-mail, but only when I have pasted in stuff into the e-mail body, not if I write everything directly into the e-mail body.
That's what I did on my phone, I wrote everything directly in a short message.

Anyone knows what this is?
Appreceate any help.

Comment: Can you give more information about the font and size that you used and what was the result when sent?

Comment: I see that if I look in the SENT-folder on my Outlook app on iPhone, the text looks normal, all same font-size. When I look at the email from my Outlook client on my computer, it looks as described. That version is also the version that was received by the others. When I check the font, it actually sais "Calibri 11px" on the normal text, and "HelveticaNeue 11px" on the lagre text. So, actually, same font-size, but different font. HelveticaNeue being visually twice the size.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : No solution except switching to another email client.

Long answer : This problem has existed for at least 5 years now.
Microsoft blames iOS and no fixes coming.

Posts I have found in chronological order:

- [Word for iOS Helvetica Neue font issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-for-ios-helvetica-neue-font-issue/b44a5e60-4290-4289-a02e-33c5f1026f49) (2017)
  Ryan Mon1, a Microsoft Agent, blames iOS changes.
- [Outlook iOS App - Font & Line Spacing Issues](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-ios-app-font-line-spacing-issues/2e26523b-8152-4ea5-a7b0-e6d23728e481?auth=1&page=1)
  (2018)
  Long running thread up to 2019, with no answer by Microsoft.
- [IOS Outlook App Font](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/ios-outlook-app-font/2239f666-7b83-4c5d-a0b2-8e8e570a20d4)
  (2021)
  Answer: "there is currently no way to change fonts in Outlook App on Iphone
  or any smartphone".

Comment: Thank you for answering! :)